# asp.net web api Authorize 302 code

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-302

When I send request from client side I received 302 code and redirect to login but 
next I received:

Console log: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/........................ No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:' is therefore not allowed access.
 Error: Response with status: 0  for URL: null`

ApiController:

```
[Authorize]
        public string Get()
        { }
```

I would like to return status code 401 or something like that.

Comment: you are not have permission to call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/...` from your origin `https://localhost:44315`

Comment: Yes, i know but I want to response 401 or data to client, no redirect

Comment: You need to elaborate more and give more code

Comment: What about using an `ActionFilter` and check the response in `OnActionExecuted` event and return correct `HttpResponseMessage` and `HttpStatusCode`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not enabled CORS in your API or that you are using cookie authentication instead of Token based auth.

To return a 401 instead of a 302 you could write some Custom Owin Middleware that would check what your controller is returning and alter the response to make it fit your needs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Middleware
{
    using Microsoft.Owin;

    public sealed class MyCustomMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        public MyCustomMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
            : base(next)
        {
        }

        public override async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {

            // Code here executed before reaching the controller
            await Next.Invoke(context);
            // Code here executed after reaching the controller, includes the response
            // check response here and modify it to suit your needs
            if(context.Response.StatusCode == 302) {
              var headers = context.Response.Headers;
              headers.Keys.ForEach(k => headers.Remove(k));
              context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
              context.Response.ContentType = string.Empty;
              context.Response.ContentLength = null;
              await context.Response.WriteAsync(string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in startup.cs

```
        app.Use<Middleware.MyCustomMiddleware>();
```

Comment: Yes, I using cookie authentication, but MyCustomMiddleware nothing change, I have the same error and 302.

Comment: Try to overwrite the response with some text if you can, also look at the headers, they might contain a redirect header, which you can try to remove.

Comment: I use  return Content(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden"); when !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, but how I should protected web api ? Now I use cookie authentication but it is not good.

Comment: Did my answer help you in your original question (returning 401) ? If so please mark it as resolved. For your other question I recommend posting another StackOverflow question, because it requires a different answer.

Comment: No it didn't, still redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/........................

Comment: I think after this MyCustomMiddleware, when is 401 is redirect to login.microsoftonline.com.

Comment: Can I set MyCustomMiddleware for only ApiControllers or exclude controller to check ?